# How can I get a net framework version of the obfuscator at javascriptobfuscator.com?

Tags: javascript, .net, windows, obfuscation

I love the obfuscator, but if the website ever goes down then I am SOL. So how can I get a working version that I can run on my PC?

The full URL is http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx

p.s. I'm **NOT looking for a different obfuscator**. I'm looking for **THIS ONE** secifically.

Answer (score 1):

Since they don't seem to use javascript to obfuscate but they obfuscate this server side, the answer is simple, you can't.

Your best bet if you really want it is to contact them and try to license it from them, but you won't be able to get it by yourself since the code that provides the encoded javascript is not made available.

Comment: You're not going to get a diferent answer from someone else, if the code isn't available, it just isn't, nothing you can do about it except contact them as i said.